# A computation of a dimension of a space of sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-cohomology

Let $S$ be a finite set with $m$ elements in $\mathbb{P}^n$. Associate to $S$ the subscheme $Y$ such that the ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}_Y$ of $Y$ is the ideal sheaf of $S$ to the power $t$, where $t\geq 1$. Let $d\geq 1$.
How to see that
$$
h^0(\mathbb{P}^n,\mathcal{O}_Y(d) ) = m\left(
\begin{array}{c}
t+n-1\\
n
\end{array}
\right).
$$

Thanks!!

Comment: What have you tried? Can you do this for $t=1$? If yes, can you write a filtration for $\mathcal{O}_Y$ with larger $t$?

Comment: Thanks Mohan for your answer. For $t=1$ of course it's easy. What do you mean by filtration for $\mathcal{O}_Y$ ??

Comment: Say, for $t=2$, you have a filtration, $0\to I_S/I_S^2\to \mathcal{O}_Y\to \mathcal{O}_S\to 0$. (Also, I hope you have noticed that the right side of your answer does not depend on $d$).